# Chrome column layout issue with jumping iframe content

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, column-count

I put videos (in ) to the 3 column layout using "column-count 3". And every time when I hit play button on the second or third video on top, I got it jumped to the bottom of the previous column. It happens only in Chrome. In Firefox it's perfect as expected.

I tried to apply all the tips regarding similar questions I've found on StackOverflow, however, none of them works for me (including addition of the translate property to the wrapping container). Could you please help me with that?

Here is my code (Jade):

```
            .column-list.column-list--three
            each video in content['pausecast']
                    +video-panel(video)
```

---

```
mixin video-panel(obj)
.video-panel
    .aspect-ratio
       iframe(scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/"+ obj.youtubeId.replace('watch?v=',''))
```

---

```
.aspect-ratio
    position relative
    width 100%
    height 0
    padding-bottom 51%
    // transform translate3d(0,0,0)


.aspect-ratio iframe
    position absolute
    width 100%
    height 100%
    left 0
    top 0

.video-panel
    border-bottom grey 2px solid
    margin-bottom 40px
```

I definitely cannot go to any fixed heights or widths as I need it to be flexible while resizing + keeping correct aspect ratio. So applied changes should be minimised as possible. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution that worked for me was to get rid of column-count and use other grid instead. Used Jeet and col(4/12, cycle: 3). That's it. Very weird behaviour of column-count + position absolute.